# Can I see the stored WLAN settings on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

Ist it possible to see the settings of my known WLANs stored on my iPhone? I only know that I can access the settings of the current network when I am logged into one.

Edit: The iPhone is not jailbroken and I do not intend to jailbreak it.

Comment: There's a .db file that stores all the BSSIDs and encrypted passwords to all the wireless networks you've connected to, but you cannot access the database unless you're JailBroken. In fact, there are some JailBreak apps that even show you the passwords.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I should have mentioned that the iPhone is not jailbroken and will not be jailbroken. I thought there might be a possibility to see these settings from the original iOS or iTunes.

Comment: are you on OSX or Windows? Do you encrypt your iPhone backups?

Comment: I am on Windows. To tell the truth, I do not know if the backup is encrypted. My backup is stored in the iCloud.

Comment: If it's stored in iCloud you are likely (not guaranteed) encrypted.  I don't know that you would want to review your WLAN settings on your computer instead of your iPhone though (this obviously isn't a portable solution).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, jailbreaking is the easiest way. But if you really don't want to, you can back up the iPhone and use a tool like [Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com) to view the .db file that stores the settings.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, unless you jailbreak.

However, jailbreaking is now so easy and painless that there really is little reason not to do it. For example, just [follow this guide](http://greenpois0n.com/2012/05/absinthe-2-0-has-arrived/) if you're on iOS 5.1.1.

After you jailbreak, you'll be able get apps like "WiFi Passwords" in Cydia which do what you want.

Comment: I once had jailbreaked/jailbroken my iPhone. But I find cydia way too confusing. Additionally, I felt losing the comfort of iOS. Thus I had restored my iPhone to factory settings.